# If the boundary of an open connected set $\Omega$ of class $C^1$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $\Omega$ is bounded?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set.

I know bounded boundary doesn't imply bounded set, but what if we consider the boundary of an open connected set of class $C^1$ (i.e. the boundary $\partial \Omega$ is locally the graph of a $C^1$ function)-

If the boundary of a connected open set $\Omega$ of class $C^1$ is bounded then $\Omega$ is bounded?

Comment: Have you thought about this? For instance, have you thought about an example where the boundary is bounded but $\Omega$ is not, and considered whether that example can be modified to have smooth boundary? (Or whether it already _has_ a smooth boundary?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, for example $\mathbb{R}^2 - R$, where $R$ is a closed segment. But the definition of $C^1$ boundary are not met for the two points at the end of the segment, does it?

Comment: True, that example does not answer the question. But there are very simple _analogous_ examples. I mean can you think of any bounded smooth curves?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\Omega = \{ x \in \Bbb R^n | \| x \| > 1 \}$

It is open connected, and $\partial \Omega$ is $C^1$ but $\Omega$ is not bounded